# Convert Decimal to BCD32

Tags: javascript

I am trying to take a number from a user input like 1325.0 and convert it to BCD32 to enter it into a webpage. 
The number the user inputs runs from 0100.0 to 1799.9 and has only 1 decimal place.
I know i need to use to split the number up between the First 4 digits and the Decimal place and convert each of them with parseInt add them together.

One example below takes and converts a XX.XX number to BCD where n1 is the first 2 digits and n2 is the last 2.

```
var bcd = (parseInt(n1.charCodeAt(0) - 0x30 )<<12) + (parseInt(n1.charCodeAt(1) - 0x30 )<<8) + (parseInt(n2.charCodeAt(0) - 0x30 )<<4) + parseInt(n2.charCodeAt(1) - 0x30 );
```

I can figure out how to get the first 4 numbers separate for the decimal, but not sure on the conversion equation.

The program i have reads the BCD32 number and displays it.  I need to convert over to it to enter it.

Comment: why? converting that number turns it into a thing that can't actually be displayed properly on a webpage.

Comment: It goes into a game the webpage sends it to the game so javascript needs to convert it to what the game can read.

Comment: if the game is running on the page as well, why would it not just accept plain numbers resulting from a `parseFloat()`?